# Simple Inner Join for comparing two values in table

Tags: mysql, join, comparison

I'm currently stuck at figuring out what could be considered a rather basic and common inner join problem:

I have two tables orders and locations:

**orders**

```
|----------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
| foreign_from_id      | foreign_to_id     |    same_triade    |
|----------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|          US          |        MX         |                   |
|          US          |        DE         |                   |
|----------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
```

**locations**

```
|----------------------|-------------------|
|       foreign_id     |       triade      |
|----------------------|-------------------|
|          US          |         AME       |
|          MX          |         AME       |
|          DE          |         EU        |
|----------------------|-------------------|
```

My code is supposed to check if the foreign_from_id and the foreign_to_id is in the same triade and return a 1 or 0 in same_triade. 
Helping me figuring out this one would help me solve a lot of my SQL problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I've tried to solve it myself but I'm struggling. I'd assume it to be low effort for someone experienced in mysql...

Comment: I expect you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from @PeterHe's query I wrote this:

```
UPDATE orders
INNER JOIN locations fl ON orders.foreign_from_id=fl.foreign_id 
INNER JOIN locations tl ON orders.foreign_to_id=tl.foreign_id 
SET orders.same_triade = (CASE WHEN fl.triade=tl.triade THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cfrhWey8oVKGK83XELJCsb/5)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT o.foreign_from_id, o.foreign_to_id, CASE WHEN fl.triade=ol.triade THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS same_triade
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN locations fl
ON o.foreign_from_id=fl.foreign_id 
INNER JOIN locations tl
ON o.foreign_to_id=tl.foreign_id;
```